# Can memset be parallelized on 4 cores?

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, winapi, memory

I am not sure to that. Can I write a large memset (for example 10 MB), on four cores to gain speedup with this?

Is such ram-chip parallelization possible at all, and also how big are time costs of firing other threads - is it more than a millisecond or less?

Comment: such an operation would probably only get slower if you parallelized it - you'd have multiple cores/cpus fighting for access to the memory bus.

Comment: Maybe use the specific instruction to move more bytes one time will help you. use paralelisation will have advantage only when the data are distributed in different memory part.

Comment: The only case in which a parallel `memset` might be faster is with very very large memory blocks on a NUMA architecture where each core is working on memory attached to its processor.

Comment: @MarcB and you'd need to "join" threads, possibly wasting extra time if scheduling isn't very uniform across the CPUs.

Comment: @SegFault But 10 MB, unless somehow explicitly allocated from different nodes, are likely to come from the same node.

Comment: If `memset` could benefit from such a desin on your architecture, wouldn't you already had it? If you don't trust the people who wrote your `memset` to provide an optimized implementation, you shouldn't trust them to do much of anything because this is like one of the first things library authors make sure to get right.

Comment: you are more likely to get a better speedup using a pipelined, partially unrolled SIMD based memset (16 bytes per inst, 256b to 2kb+ per loop). however, depending on your use of the memory, zero'ing out the massive block might be counter productive.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze For 10MB it's not even worth thinking about it parallelising, at least if you are on a reasonably recent single-socket PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pointing out a right question, at the same time it is difficult to give a simple answer to it. There are several aspects involved.

1. Overhead of starting new threads (or picking them from some cache);
2. Contension on the memory bus.
3. The aspects above differ and have very different cost for different platforms.

Bigger PCs have several memory buses. Smaller ones have only one. On a one memory bus system this does not make any sense. If your system has several memory buses (channels) your array of data may have arbitrary split between memory banks. If it will happen that the whole array sits in the same memory bank, the parralelisation will be useless. Figuring out the layout of your array is an overhead again. In other words before splitting the operation between cores it is necessary to figure out if this is worth doing or not.

Simple answer is that these difficult to predict overheads will most likely will consume the benefit and make the overall result worse.

At the same time for a really huge memory area on some architectures it makes sense.

Comment: Would it be worth determining on program start if it is worth parrallizing the *memset* and decide at run-time?

Comment: This maybe should happen during the start of the OS. The CPU it the same for all apps that will be started. On the other hand the split between memory banks will be all the times different and not easy to evaluate.

Comment: On modern CPU's, a single CPU core can easily saturate all memory buses when writing zeroes. So even then there's no point in parallelization.

Comment: Can you give any numbers for some exact CPU? Like speed of emitting memory orders from one CPU core and speed of the memory controller? I will be happy to see this.